# Getting number of possible anagrams from a generic string, need a fast solution

Tags: c#

I am currently working on an assignment where I need to write a small program that will take a generic string and should output how many possible anagrams that could be generated from the string.
The string that is the input can be up to 100 chars long and could include both lowercase and uppercase, in this case both lowercase and uppercase are considered distinct. The output should only be how many possible combinations, so I don't need to output the actual anagrams.The maximum timelimit is 1 second per string.

I have tried a number of diffrent ways of doing this, but one conclusion is that this should be solvable using some type of mathemathical algorithm.

The latest code I have tried with is this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line;
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var uniqueStringArr = removeDuplicates(line);

        Console.WriteLine(countDistinctPermutations(new string(uniqueStringArr)));
    }
}

private static char[] removeDuplicates(string line)
{
    var list = line.ToList();

    return list.Distinct().ToArray();
}

static int MAX_CHAR = 100;

// Utility function to find factorial of n. 
static int factorial(int n)
{
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        fact = fact * i;

    return fact;
}

// Returns count of distinct permutations 
// of str. 
static int countDistinctPermutations(String str)
{
    int length = str.Length;

    int[] freq = new int[MAX_CHAR];

    // finding frequency of all the lower case 
    // alphabet and storing them in array of 
    // integer 
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (str[i] >= 'a')
            freq[str[i] - 'a']++;

    // finding factorial of number of appearances 
    // and multiplying them since they are 
    // repeating alphabets 
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++)
        fact = fact * factorial(freq[i]);

    // finding factorial of size of string and 
    // dividing it by factorial found after 
    // multiplying 
    return factorial(length) / fact;
}
```

The thing is that this code does not give the correct answer for all my testcases.
The following sample data was provided for me :

**Input string | Number of possible anagrams**

at | 2

ordeals | 5040

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | 403291461126605635584000000

abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm | 49229914688306352000000

abcdABCDabcd | 29937600

My code fixes the first two examples, but I get completly diffrent numbers for the other 3.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem because I am running out of ideas ?

/Andreas

Comment: Hi I don't understand the output here. If we look at each at (2 characters) 2! =2 ,
ordeals 7! = 5040, alphabet 26! = 403291461126605635584000000, then the one in the middle 13!  (take out duplicates) = 6227020800, final one 8! (if you consider upper and lower different) = 40320

Comment: Simplest fail test case I can think of is "aab"

Comment: You might want to consider using int64 instead of int no?   Not sure your code would break if you go over int.MaxValue.  I tried int I = int.MaxValue; i+i return -2 :)

Comment: @Richard The one in the middle is 26!/2^13 = 4.9229915e+22.

Comment: Yes i saw that the issue was that I used the wrong type, but as the string can be up to 100 chars long int64 will not be enough, so I changed to double instead but the output is still wrong as I get the scientific notation out when converting to string, does anyone know of a good way to convert the double to like a large non decimal number string ?

Comment: in fact as @Pautodidactic points out, BigIngeger is the way to go.   And do not forget to use System.Numerics.

Comment: I made an embarrassing mistake in the denominator of the fraction which I corrected it.

Comment: This is just a counting problem. There are formulas for the number of permutations of a set of things. You’ll need to account for duplicates from non-distinct characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    string line;
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{line} -> {countDistinctPermutations(line)}");
    }
}
static BigInteger factorial(int n)
{
    double fact = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        fact = fact * i;
    return fact;
}
static BigInteger countDistinctPermutations(String str)
{
    // get a collection of {letter,occurences}
    var duplicates = Array.GroupBy(p => p).Select(x => new { x.Key, count = x.Count() }).Where(x => x.count > 1);
    BigInteger result = factorial(str.Length);
    // foreach letter where occurence > 1 divide total permutations by the permutations for the occurence value (occurrence!)
    foreach (var d in duplicates)
    {
        result /= factorial(d.count);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
static BigInteger Factorial(long x)
{
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : x * Factorial(x-1);
}

private static BigInteger NumberOfDistinctPermutationOf(string str)
{
    BigInteger dividend = Factorial(str.Length);

    foreach (char chr in str)
    {
        dividend /= Factorial(str.Count(c => c == chr));
        str = str.Replace(chr.ToString(), string.Empty);
    }

    return dividend;
}
```

Description:

- [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-3.1) Struct: Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.
- [`Enumerable.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)  Method: Returns a number that represents how many elements in the specified sequence satisfy a condition.
- [`String.Replace(String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) Method: Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.
- `GetNumberOfDistinctPermutation` Method: Divides factorial of the length of the string by factorial of the number of occurrences of the `char` and then removes all occurrences of the `char`, for each `char` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I only write code for a week so it's not that pretty but it works 100%.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(Solution(inputData));
}
static char[] convert(string text) // converting string to char[]
{
    char[] newString = new char[text.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        newString[i] = text[i];
    }
    return newString;
}
static double CalculateFctorial(double number) // calc. factorial
{
    double factorial = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        factorial *= i;
    return factorial;
}
static int CountOcc(string text, char zet) // counting occurrences
{                     
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == zet)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
static double Solution(string text) // the soluton, counting occurences of
                                    // each char in string and each factorial
{
    double net = 0;
    double sol = 1;
    char[] newText = convert(text);
    for (int i = 0; i <= newText.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text.Length > 0)
        {
            net = CountOcc(text, newText[i]);
            sol = sol * CalculateFctorial(net);

            if (newText[i] == text[0])
            { text = text.Trim(text[0]); }
        }
    }
    double solution = CalculateFctorial(newText.Length) / sol;
    return solution;
}
```